How do I unmarshal a CSV with repeated column names with gocsv
I have an incoming CSV file with repeated column names and no easy way to change that fact. For instance, the incoming CSV has 2 Name columns and 2 Asset Type columns.
I set up a receiving structure and gocsv.UnmarshalBytes() works fine. As expected, when I run gocsv.MarshalBytes() (or view each individual line) there is only one of each column. Is there a way to handle this situation and not lose the repeated columns?
ShouldAlignDuplicateHeadersWithStructFieldOrder looks promising but seems to be utterly undocumented and has no effect.

https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv/issues/77 looks like it's already an open feature request on gocsv.  https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv/blob/master/decode_test.go#L590 There's a test for it.  It appears to ensure the first of the duplicate columns provides the value in the struct

Yes that's exactly what I'm seeing (the first column parsed is the value used). Hmm. Feature request from 2017. Probably not going to happen, but thanks for finding that.

It ends up being quite easy to implement a UnmarshalCSV that can turn duplicate columns into a []string.
// Names is a custom type to handle multiple "name" fields in the CSV.
type Names []string

// UnmarshalCSV is a custom unmarshaller to handle duplicate "name" headers.
func (n *Names) UnmarshalCSV(csv string) error {
    *n = append(*n, csv)
    return nil
}

// Person represents a row in the CSV with an Age and multiple Names.
type Person struct {
    Age   int   `csv:"age"`
    Names Names `csv:"name"` // Use the custom Names type for duplicate "name" fields
}

Then gocsv will unmarshal it as usual.
Full example at https://go.dev/play/p/ANSB1if4tEQ
You don't also have to write that CSV back out, do you?

I was thinking of writing a custom unmarshal and it may come down to that. But yes, unfortunately, I do have to write out a new CSV file. This is some sanitation work. However, I reached out to the data source peeps and I think we can make some changes to the input so I may be clear. If forced to do so at gunpoint I could split the lines myself on the commas and deal with it, but I hope to avoid that.

I don't think you have to go that far.  You can useencoding/csv to do the parsing - it just hands you []string and has no concept of headers or anything, so you can do the processing from there.
